# Python XPath processing library supporting 'local-name()' function

Tags: xml, xpath, python-2.x

In my XSLT stylesheet I have the expression like this:

```
//*[local-name()='record']/@*[local-name()='internalId']
```

local-name() function is used here to avoid working with prefixes and namespaces. I used it for XML like this:

```
...
<body>
  <plat:record rom:internalId='5'>
...
```

to get the '5'

I would like to know, is there a Python library supporting standard XPath, so that I could use the expression like above without any modifications. I prefer the standard Python library if possible, not 3rd party.
Please recommend me something. I will appreciate the little example of using it.
I'm working with Python 2.x.

Thanks in advance

Comment: lxml supports XPath and local-name() but you really should not ignore namespaces. They're quite important in properly designed XMLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lie Ryan was right. Here's the way I've solved my problem:

```
from lxml import etree

# ...

responseXmlRoot = etree.fromstring(response.content)
operationStatus = responseXmlRoot.xpath("//*[local-name()='status']/@*[local-name()='isSuccess']")
if not operationStatus or operationStatus[0] != 'true':
    errorDetails = responseXmlRoot.xpath("//*[local-name()='detail']/descendant::*/text()")
    raise Exception("Exception when trying to post user's credentials to NetSuitr. " + str(errorDetails[0]))
```

Comment: This is not how you should have solved your problem. Listen to Lie Ryan's other advice and handle namespaces properly. It's really simple: http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes (I encourage you to re-write your answer.)